# Is it possible to detect low power mode using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have a website with a background video. And have an issue, when a user is on Low power mode on IOS devices (iPhone, Mac, etc.).

Is it possible to handle **only** low power mode and set fallback image instead of video with play button?

I saw a variant with a `suspend` event, but it fired also when the video fully loaded, so it's not a correct solution for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [javaScript battery API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API) to track the battery status

Comment: As I see battery API isn't provide to check status of low power mode

Comment: Also, this API isn't support in Safari and many other browsers =(

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found a solution:
The most correct way, in my opinion, is just handle error throwing (in catch block) and set a fallback image instead of video.

FYI: This solution is relevant only when the video is in the background (from a UX point of view)

So the solution is:

`

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (videoRef.current) {
    videoRef.current?
      .play()
      .then(() => {})
      .catch((error) => {
        setVideoPaused(true);

        return error;
      });
  }
}, []);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Check this link in a low power mode https://video-dev.github.io/can-autoplay/

You will see that the error you get is `"NotAllowedError"` because the request is not allowed in the current context. That really goes for any situation where autoPlay is prevented by the userAgent or the system settings.

So throw it in the catch and set state for the fallback like mentioned above

```
.catch((error) => {
 if (error.name === "NotAllowedError") {
  //low power mode
}
```

Seems to work pretty reliably